# Why is my .htaccess and .htpasswd not working?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, html, .htpasswd

I have `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` files in the directory that has png files that I want to protect.

**.htaccess**

```
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Co to za nielegalne grzebanie w plikach, juz dzwonie na milicje."
  AuthUserFile ./.htpasswd
  Require valid-user
```

**.htpasswd**

```
test:$apr1$hp25fckm$QSSnnAWn6b5lWDScZ7h7t0
```

and I don't know why it's not working?

Comment: Where is the `.htpasswd` file?

Comment: Are you really on Apache 2.2?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> AuthUserFile ./.htpasswd
> ```

The file-path to your password file is most certainly wrong. This should be an absolute filesystem path. (Or a relative path, relative to the `ServerRoot`).

For example, depending on the file-path to your document root, this should be something like the following instead:

```
AuthUserFile /www/user/public_html/images/.htpasswd
```

However, the `.htpasswd` file should be at a location outside of the `DocumentRoot` (outside of the public HTML space). It shouldn't be in the directory you are trying to protect.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_file.html#authuserfile