# .htaccess & .htpasswd

Tags: authentication, .htaccess

I have this project where I have a front and back.
My login file is simple if the login and password are in my database then I'm directed to a page in the back, otherwise I can't go.
I login into the backoffice without a problem but I wanted to protect the back and directories.

I'm trying to lock my backoffice with `.htaccess` which worked I can't access the backoffice directories but I also can't login anymore.

Here are my two files.

Content of `.htaccess`:

```
Deny from all 
Options -Indexes


AuthType Basic
AuthName "KW"
AuthUserFile /.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Content of `.passwd`:

```
root:passwordhere
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> AuthUserFile /.htpasswd
> ```

In addition to the "typo" as mentioned in @Glorfindel's answer (`.htpasswd` vs `.passwd`), the argument passed to the `AuthUserFile` directive should be an absolute filesystem-path, not a document-root relative URL-path, as you appear to be using here.

See [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1056622/49157) to [a related question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1056614/why-is-my-htaccess-and-htpasswd-not-working) for an example. See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68123218/369434) to a similar question on StackOverflow that goes into more detail.

Errors with HTTP authentication are very often caused by using an incorrect file-path to the password file.

However, you also need to remove the Apache 2.2 `Deny from all` directive on the first line. By default, on Apache 2.4, this will override the `Require` directive and block all access with a 403 Forbidden - the prompt for a password is suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a typo in your post or in your system, but

```
AuthUserFile /.htpasswd
```

points to a file named `.htpasswd` and your post mentions `.passwd`.

Comment: Also, the file-path provided to the `AuthUserFile` directive "looks wrong" - this should be an _absolute_ file-path. The `Deny from all` directive is also erroneous, as mentioned in [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1068911/49157).